# Function to write in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have written a function which writes data in an excel using POI. However at present I have to specify the rows and columns where the data is to be written in the parameters. I want to make this function generic that it should write the data automatically in the next column for a particular test case and should change the row when the test case changes.

```
public void WritetoExcel(String filepath,String DatatoWrite,int RowNum, int ColNum, int sheetnumber) throws Exception
    {   
         FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(filepath);
         ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheetAt(sheetnumber);

        try{
            Row  = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
            Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (Cell == null) {
                Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);
                Cell.setCellValue(DatatoWrite);
                } else {
                    Cell.setCellValue(DatatoWrite);
                }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw (e);
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me how can I do this?

Comment: could you specify the test case?

Comment: The testcase is to write orderID and its status everytime a transaction is run. When the test case is run again, a new order ID and its corresponding status would be generated which I want to write in the excel again

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. How do you recognize the test case changed, whats the criteria?

Comment: is your method called every time you write 1 cell?

Comment: I am making a transaction through an ecommerce website and everytime I start an Order# is generated and a page is displayed success/failure/ . I want to save this status along with this orderID. and when I restart the txn I want to again save the new Order# and status in a new row.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void WritetoExcel(String filepath, String DatatoWrite, int sheetnumber, boolean newTest) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheetAt(sheetnumber);

        try {
            if (newTest) {
                Row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum++); 
                cellnum=0;
            }
            Cell = Row.creatCell(cellnum++);
            Cell.setCellValue(DatatoWrite);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

so as i understand it, you have a blank excel sheet, which you want to fill with data. therefore you need to create a new row every time your boolean is true and always a new cell. the boolean is only true, if a new test case is run. make rownum and cellnum a member variable and set their value at startup to 0. this code requires an empty excel file.